# How to extend jquery with method that sets target's html?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to extend jquery with a simple function that creates a table and adds headers to it. So, the idea is simple: you select a div, construct a _table with .table(headers) method and set div's html to be the _table inside the function. I supposed that $(this).append(_table); will do the setting of div's html but it does not. How to do it correctly?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $.fn.extend({
                table: function (headers) {
                    var _table = $('<table></table>');
                    console.log(_table.html());

                    if (headers.length > 0) {
                        var gridContent = '<thead><tr>';

                        $.each(headers, function (index, element) {
                            gridContent += ('<th>' + element + '</th>');
                        });

                        gridContent += ('</tr></thead>');
                        console.log(gridContent);
                        _table.append(gridContent);
                    }
                }
            });

            $('#container').table(['id', 'name', 'city']);
        </script>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="grid-container"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside your extend, this hold the element that you try to put the table inside to.
So the code can be like this:

```
$.fn.extend({
    table: function(headers) {
        var table = $('<table></table>');
        if(headers.length > 0){
            var gridContent = '<thead><tr>';
            $.each(headers, function (index, element) {
                gridContent += ('<th>' + element + '</th>');
            });
            gridContent += ('</tr></thead>');
            table.append(gridContent);
            $(this).append(table);
        }
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wY8L2/

So, why this it did not worked with you? Because you are calling the function to create the table before the `<div>` loaded. your script with the code :

```
$('#container').table(['id', 'name', 'city']);
```

Should be executed after the `<div></div>`
or after the onload event (like this):

```
$(function(){
    $('#container').table(['id', 'name', 'city']);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your HTML to `this` instead of `$(this)` like this:

```
this.append(_table);

// or better (because your selector can select possibly more than one DOM element)

this.each(function() {
    jQuery(this).append(_table);
    return false; // break the loop after first element to only append to first element, and overall only once.
});
```

You can find an example here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.fn.extend/

Ah jo, and that what @Thanasis Grammatopoulos said in the end of his solution.

You can place your extend function where ever you want. But call it after the DOM is ready.

```
// wait for DOM to be ready...
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#container').table(['id', 'name', 'city']);
});
```